# Codeigniter Pagination class limitation

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new to Codeigniter, and I have trouble with the pagination class.

From CI document: (I do studied it carefully and practiced it.)

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';

$config['total_rows'] = '200';

$config['per_page'] = '20';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

It works quite well, when I do practice at local host.

How can I pass more parameters for the `base_url` value?

Assumed I must pass **mypara** to **page** function as below.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/mypara/';
```

It doesn't work then. How can I joined my parameter (mypara) in the base_url?

It seems it doesn't support passing parameters to base_url.

Comment: have you read the documentation ? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: re-read **Customizing the Pagination** and search the http://www.codeigniter.com forums, this question has been asked again

Comment: found it, http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/143280/P15/ read codeigniter forums, there are many questions that have been answered in there.

Comment: He hey, if my answer was correct please mark it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer on codeigniter forum. http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/143280/P15T here are many questions that have been answered in there.

Comment: yes, it meet what I want totally. I fixed my issue via `$config['uri_segment'] = '4';` from your useful url.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent tutorial from Nettuts on Pagination with COdeigniter

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/

You might also change this

```
$config['uri_segment'] = '2';
```

to 3 or 4